# what is the best pratice to save radio button list choice in database? ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, database

I was wondering what would be the best way to store the choice made of a radio button list in the database.

Should we store the index, item or the value? Storing the index for example would make it easy to populate the radio button list later from the database but it makes it hard to read the database entry directly if needed.
Should we store maybe both index and value?

Thanks ahead.

Comment: The index is irrelevant, store the value, for example an ID. I guess that all radio-button items contain a text to display and a value to identify them. The latter is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good idea is to prepare following structure of tables:

- Dictionaries
- Values

Dictionaries represent list of possible radio button or drop down list types and values store list of items of a particular RBL/DDL type.

Tables should look like:

```
Dictionaries
------------
dictionaryID PK
description
```

and

```
Values
------
valueID PK
dictionaryID FK
value
```

Then you can reference from your model/view model entity to valueID.

```
SomeEntity
----------
someEntityID PK
someRadioChoice FK(valueID)
```

And of course if you want to populate a radio button or drop down list you can simply query values with some dictionaryID in where clause.

Comment: Seems like a strong structure. Is it worth to do it even if it is like 2 or 3 choices in a radio button list? Also is it really like that in "real life", meaning for live websites?

Comment: For sure it's a good choice for a big size project. I think it has some pros. For instance it gives you ability to add new choices and dictionaries on the fly. It gives you also some sort of order, because you have all your dictionaries in one place. Of course you can even hard-code your radio button list choices in your aspx/cshtml/vbhtml files, but I think its always good to be opened for changes and further development of the project. I was contributing with the project which used mentioned structure, it has been used for many years and worked well.

Comment: With such model you can store every other possible radiobuttons/dropdownlists you need. 
Seems be more flexible then my variant.

Answer (score 1):

Use a lookup table for storing your listitem specified information like text and use the value of the list item as (part) of primary key. Then just store the value as Tim Schmelter says.[image: like this]

Comment: So the lookUpTable contains all the pairs of `SelectedItem` and `SelectedValue' (PK) of my radio button list and in my table I store only `SelectedValue` (FK)? To complete with best practices, I assume I should bind the radio button list from the look up table?

Comment: I would do so. At least it was common by projects in my team. Still better then hardcode text/value pairs and still simple.